# How can I redirect users to different pages based on their domain after login in Gramex

Tags: gramex

I have a list of users from different domains and each of the users must be redirected to a different page based on their domain once the user logs in.

Let's say I have three users and the mapping is shown below:

```
xyz@domain1.com redirects -> index.html
abc@domain2.com redirects -> index2.html
def@domain3.com redirects -> index3.html

login:
pattern: /$YAMLURL/login
handler: DBAuth
kwargs:
   auth:
    membership:
        hd: [domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com]
```

Is there a way I can add the URLs to this endpoint in gramex.yaml?